# What makes this output change?

Tags: python, output

I do not understand what effects the output to change for following code:

```
class Friend:
   def __init__(self, name):
      self.name = name
      print(name + " friend")

   def getname(self):
      return self.name

   def removefriend(self):
      print(self.name + " no friend")
      self.name += " (removed))
```

First Task:

```
paul = Friend("Paul")
paul.removefriend()
print(paul.getname())
// Output: Paul friend, Paul no friend, Paul (removed)
```

Second Task:

```
paul = Friend("Paul")
print(paul.getname())
// This actually prints: Paul friend, Paul
```

I dont get what makes the simple output `Paul` disappear in the first task? How does `removefriend` have an impact on `getname` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have implemented a method called removefriend and you are using it in your task 1. It removes your friend when you use following function **removefriend()**.

Comment: I know that, but I do not delete the object Paul? The removefriend() method just prints out something? Why can't I print the name of Paul despite removing it?

Comment: @JushKillaB This part explicitly changes the name : self.name += " (removed)). It is not just printing.

Comment: As @JushKillaB mentioned, once you use that line you are adding ((removed)) to name. So it changes the name.

Comment: I do get that as well. But when I call getname() why does it not print "Paul(removed))" as the new name is self.name+="(removed)"?

Comment: Well, it does print "Paul(removed))" with your getName function.